# jQuery/Javascript runs on local but not on Heroku

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku

This is my app on Heroku: http://mighty-brushlands-6367.herokuapp.com/ and this is how it SHOULD look, as it does locally:

[image]

Well I did some googling. I check this solution: [JQuery events are not working on heroku in production but work in development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946575/jquery-events-are-not-working-on-heroku-in-production-but-work-in-development) and others.

I went ahead to run `heroku run rake assets:precompile` but still can't get the effects to kick in on Heroku. This is how my `application.js` looks like:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap
//= require textEffect
```

I need some guidance. I'm a hungry-for-knowledge newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add

```
group :production, :staging do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

To the Gemfile and commit again to Heroku

Answer (score 0):

Your Heroku app is getting a 404 error on the application.js & application.css files which leads me to believe it is not getting pushed to Heroku in the first place.

Try running `rake assets:precompile` in development, then the usual steps `git add .` , then  `git commit`, and then `git push`.